# JPA mapping with non-primary key. The column name in two tables also differ

Tags: hibernate, jpa, mapping

There are two DB tables, say
1. Table A with primary key as aId. A has a column by name orderNo.
2. Table B with primary key as bId. B has a column by name salesOrderNo.

A.orderNo is same as B.salesOrderNo and also, for one entry in table A corresponding to a particular orderNo, there can be many entries in table B having the same salesOrderNo.

How to define this OneToMany (EntityA:EntityB) relationship.

I have tried the following and have run into issues:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "A_KEY")
    private String aId;

    @Column(name = "ORDER_NO")
    private String orderNo;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "salesOrderNo")
    List<B> b;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "B_KEY")
    private String bId;

    @Column(name="SALES_ORDER_NO")
    private String salesOrderNo;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "orderNo")
    @JsonIgnore
    private A a;
}
```

The error I see during the application start up is:

Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: orderNo in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(A) and its related supertables and secondary tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Entity A,

```java
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "SALES_ORDER_NO", referencedColumnName = "ORDER_NO")
List<B> b;
```

And in Entity B,

```java
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "SALES_ORDER_NO", referencedColumnName = "ORDER_NO", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@JsonIgnore
private A a;
```

The reason for both `@JoinColumn` looks same, because they are the same mapping.

From the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html)

> If the join is for a OneToOne or ManyToOne mapping using a foreign key mapping strategy, the foreign key column is in the table of the source entity or embeddable.

Best way to understand JPA mapping is to think about the table structure and the SQL want JPA to produce. In your case, evey row of `B` has a reference to some row  of `A`. But `A` doesn't have any reference to to `B`. So in table `B` will have a foreign key, in your case `SALES_ORDER_NO` which will refer to some column in table `A`, in your case `ORDER_NO`. So, no matter where you put the `@JoinColumn` you have to get foreign key and reference key right.

Since `A` doesn't have the foreign key you can remove the `@JoinColumn` from entity `A` and refer to the mapping done in `B` like this -

```java
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "a")
List<B> b;
```

To see if it actually maps the entities correctly I queried both entities using entity manager and it produced the following SQL queries for entity A

```sql
    select
        a0_.a_key as a_key1_0_0_,
        a0_.order_no as order_no2_0_0_,
        b1_.sales_order_no as sales_or2_1_1_,
        b1_.b_key as b_key1_1_1_,
        b1_.b_key as b_key1_1_2_,
        b1_.sales_order_no as sales_or2_1_2_ 
    from
        a a0_ 
    left outer join
        b b1_ 
            on a0_.order_no=b1_.sales_order_no 
    where
        a0_.a_key=?
```

And for entity B

```sql
    select
        b0_.b_key as b_key1_1_0_,
        b0_.sales_order_no as sales_or2_1_0_,
        a1_.a_key as a_key1_0_1_,
        a1_.order_no as order_no2_0_1_ 
    from
        b b0_ 
    left outer join
        a a1_ 
            on b0_.sales_order_no=a1_.order_no 
    where
        b0_.b_key=?
```

Which seems to match your description.

Comment: Thanks it worked!! Could you please add some explanation as I am a little confused seeing @JoinColumn(name = "SALES_ORDER_NO", referencedColumnName = "ORDER_NO") in both the entities. I mean name and referencedColumnName having the same values on both the end.